# PHP is_file in Win32 allways return false

Tags: php, winapi

I'm making a small app that must check if a certain file exists in the client computer.

```
$file = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\rpnt.dll";

if (is_file($file)){
 echo $file . " exists";
}else{
 echo $file . " does not exist";
}
```

Can't make this work. Any solution out there?

Comment: Are you sure PHP has permission to read that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is server side, you cannot check to see if a file exists on the client with it. Nor could you do it with javascript or almost any other client-side technology... for obvious security reasons.

The reason it's not working is because it's checked to see if 'C:\Windows\System32\rpnt.dll' exists on the server and you are probably using a linux based operating system for your web server...

Comment: I didn't explained it right, but this app is running locally with WAMPSERVER in a Win32 system.

Comment: Sorry for assuming buddy, you did say 'client computer'. Does it work for files within your document root? If so I would be lead to believe it is a problem with permissions. However, with my stock installation of WAMP is_file seems to work fine with files in my system32 directory. :S

Answer (score 0):

Try using forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes for the directory separator character. I've occasionally had trouble with PHP getting confused with backslashes in Windows file paths.

Comment: The only time I've ever had an issue with backslashes in the path are for network names `\\server\path` vs `//server/path`...  With regular directories, I've never seen an issue (And I primarily work on Win32 environment)...